# tmux changed keybinding (resizep) not working as expected

Tags: tmux

I use vim, and so I wanted to change a couple of tmux's default bindings. In particular I wanted to change the resizing commands so that e.g. ctrl-b ctrl-k resize the split up by one position. I entered the following into my .tmux.conf:

```
bind-key C-k resizep -U
```

and it works, except that it only allows me to resize by one unit at a time before I have to hit ctrl again. In other words, I can't hold down ctrl and press b followed by k a bunch of times (while still holding down ctrl), whereas I can hold down ctrl, press b, and then press the up arrow key a bunch of times.

Does anyone know exactly why this is, or how I might replicate my desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the `-r` parameter in your command:

```
bind-key -r C-k resizep -U
```

As explained in tmux man page:

```
bind-key [-cnr] [-t mode-table] key command [arguments]
                   (alias: bind)
             Bind key key to command.  By default (without -t) the primary
             key bindings are modified (those normally activated with the
             prefix key); in this case, if -n is specified, it is not neces‐
             sary to use the prefix key, command is bound to key alone.  The
             -r flag indicates this key may repeat, see the repeat-time
             option.
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. A bit embarrassed I missed it.